# Last Access Time not as expected. Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: files

A few days ago I was checking last access of some files of my own and I noticed that some of them was accessed from strange date and hours. 
I recently changed my OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04, I did a backup of my files and folders on external storage and copied them on Ubuntu 17.04. 
When I was installing the Ubuntu 17.04 I remember I created a new partition table. This is how my partition looks like now:

[image]

1. Name: `Appunti.odt`

   Last access: 6 May 2017 at 23:43:56 (Last time I opened this file it was for modification, so 10 April 2017.

   [image]
2. [image]

Who open those files? How the system determine what is last access?

Comment: We can't help unless you give an example. **[Edit]** your question and show us one of the file names and the command you used to check its modification date. Also explain what you mean by "new Ubuntu"; had you opened the files with an older version? And have you kept the same filesystem (hard drive)? We need more information.

Comment: Hi! My filesystem is ext4. Right click-Properties- Last access. With new Ubuntu I mean 17.04 version. And yes some files come from another version, but it happens also with new ones. It's like someone is opening them.

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and add the answer to all the questions I asked.

Comment: It's done terdon.

Comment: Are you using an encrypted home directory? You can check with `grep -Fe ecryptfs /proc/mounts`.

Comment: Was the date that you restored your backup to the new partition May 6?  I recently did the same thing, and all of my files have a last access date of the day I copied them into the new partition.

Comment: Here the output: http://imgur.com/a/BvZz0

Comment: So any answers?